# Can I call super in a loop in python?

Tags: python, super

How can I make the following code work, and if it's not possible what better ways are there to do this particular thing?
I can't seem to figure it out, since I believe I shouldn't create an object of the parent. Just writing super() doesn't seem to work here for me (3.6.5).

```
class Geometry(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if kwargs:
            allowed = ['lat', 'lng', ]
            for k,v in kwargs.items():
                if k in allowed:
                    setattr(self, k, v)

class Address(Geometry):
    def __init__(self, d = None):
        if d:
            for k,v in d.items():
                if k in Geometry:
                    setattr(super, k, v)
                if k in Allowed('Address'):
                    setattr(self, k, v)
```

I'm trying to push values up to the parent class, but without knowing the attribute names before they are in a list of allowed ones.

I know Geometry doesn't support membership testing as of this moment, because nothing is defined.

The `Geometry` superclass has the attributes lat, lng, name etc.
The `Allowed` helper class will return a list of strings representing allowed keys for the Address class.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're really aiming to do here. Can you show the code for `Geometry` too?

Comment: What is `self.[k]`? I've never seen that syntax before.

Comment: Please, name your variables with explicit names. d, lat, Ing etc., don't help much

Comment: I've made an update to the question now. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that you are using `super` in the wrong way.

You should initialise the super class first:

```
class Geometry(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if kwargs:
            allowed = ['lat', 'lng', ]
            for k,v in kwargs.items():
                if k in allowed:
                    setattr(self, k, v)

class Address(Geometry):
    def __init__(self, **d = None):
        super().__init__(d)
        if d:
            for k,v in d.items():
                if k in Allowed('Address'):
                    setattr(self, k, v)
```

In this way, the super class sorts itself out.

Your `Address` class can sort its own attributes out. (Helped by `Allowed`).

I've assumed that the `d` param is a dictionary just like `kwargs`.

The way you were using `super` meant to me that you should have just used `self`. (except that `k in Geometry` did not really mean anything)

Comment: You are correct in your assumption, I'm still in the jungle with a Swiss knife. Just haven't figured out all the tools yet.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to set those properties using `setattr` you won't need to use `super`, you can use `self` instead.

If you still want to use `super`, then you'll have to use it as a method;
`setattr(super(), k, v)`

Besides, I think the best solution is to pass the dictionary `d` to the constructor of `Geometry` instead of setting the values in the `Address` constructor. You can do so like this;

```
class Address(Geometry):
    def __init__(self, d = {}):
        Geometry.__init__(self, **d)
        for k, v in d.items():
            if k in Allowed('Address'):
                setattr(self, k, v)
```